# Swift - Tableview reloads only after second tap of the tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, cell

I've read 3 pages of google results and none worked for me, here's detailed description of the problem:

Every time I launch my app If I tap on the tab bar item that shows the vc that contains my table view it is empty. I have to go to another tab and return to it, just then my table view fetches. Spent 8h trying to fix it already.

Same exact VC shown with a button tap is displayed correctly and loads every time.

What i've already tried:

- triple checked if I have:
  tableView.delegate = self
  tableView.dataSource = self
- Tried moving the fetching to viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear, none worked.
- Diagnosed it, number of sections is returned but number of rows = 0, cellForRowAt never executes on first tab bar click, even tho my posts are fetched correctly.
- Tried fixing any constraints that exist, didn't work.

It simply seems like tableView.reloadData() doesn't work. I surrender, please help me!

Comment: You need to provide a **lot** more information. Describe your model object. Explain how the data gets loaded ("Fetched" into that model. (From a file? From an API call? Hard-coded?) Post your table view data source methods.)

Comment: What do you think calling `tableView.reloadData()` does?

Comment: @DuncanC i've updated my question with what you asked. Btw im fetching it from Firebase database. I was thinking .reloadData() runs the CellForRowAt method again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still haven’t provided a very clear picture. At a glance, though, I’d say you need to add a call to your table view’s `reloadData()` method inside the braces on your call to `posts(for:completion:)`. (I’m guessing about the exact name of that function since you don’t include it.)

If your `posts(for:completion:)` invokes its completion handler on a background thread then you’ll need to wrap your call to `reloadData()` in a call to `DispatchQueue.main.async()` (Since `TableView.reloadData()` is a UIKit call and you can’t do UIKit calls on a background thread.)

The code might look like this:

```
StartTestingViewController.posts(for: UUID as! String) { (posts) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.posts = posts
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

(I didn’t copy your whole viewDidLoad method, just the bit that calls your function that fetches posts.)

The `UITableView.reloadData()` method tells your table view “The number of sections/rows of data or their contents may have changed. Please re-ask your data source for contents and re-build your cells.” The table view will ask for the number of sections again, ask for the number of rows in each section, and ask for enough cells to fill the table view’s frame with cells.

If you don’t call `reloadData()` your table view has no idea that there is new data so it doesn’t reload itself.

I suspect that the reason that you can go another tab and come back and see your data is that the data has been loaded while you were on another tab, and so is available immediately. I’d have to see the exact details of your tab displaying code to be sure.

Comment: Unfortunately adding DispatchQueue didn't fix the problem. I am so hesitant to pasting any specific code here because this app is a part of my engineering thesis and I'm scared that the code would pop up in a plagiarism check. 
This bug is so bizarre.. I am 100% sure that posts are there but the tableView for some reason doesn't refresh them on the first tab bar item click

Comment: Can I maybe send you a private message with exact details of the tab displaying the code somehow?

Comment: Okay, sorry for triple comment. But thanks to your reply and the "rubber duck method" I've came into realization that I'm starting my view using a coordinator and a create() method. I've added the posts loading part there and now it started working. So thank you very much for "I’d have to see the exact details of your tab displaying code to be sure." part :D Huge thank you I wish i could somehow repay!

Comment: I would think you would be ok posting your own code on SO. If it did turn up in a plagiarism test, it's pretty easy to document that you were the one posting it. Now, if you're asking for more help online than you should for your thesis, that's a horse of a different color.